# What is the infinite version of a pairing called?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

In a category with products, if we have morphisms $f\colon A \to B$ and $g\colon A \to C$, then the morphism
$$
\langle f\ ,\ g\rangle \colon A \to B \times C
$$
is sometimes called the *pairing* of $f$ and $g$.  [According to the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pairing), you can use 'tripling', 'quadrupling' etc. to refer to the same phenomenon but for a product of $3,4,\dots$ sets, and can use 'tupling' for products in general.

I'm trying to remember if there's a word that one can use for arbitrary maps into products.  'Tupling' suggests 'tuple', which normally means an element of a product of *finitely many* objects.  It's also not a word that many people are likely to understand.

**Question** Given an object $A$ and objects $(B_i\ \colon\ i\in I)$ of a category with products and morphisms $f_i\colon A \to B_i$, we can construct a morphism
$$
\langle f_i\ \colon\ i\in I\rangle \colon A \to \prod_{i\in I} B_i
$$
Is there a name for this analogous to 'pairing' in the case of a product of two objects?  We should be able to say:

> $\langle f_i\ \colon\ i\in I\rangle$ is the ???? of the $f_i$.

Comment: ???? $=$ *product map*

Comment: @hardmath That's probably the best we can do, though I'd normally want to reserve *product* for the morphism $\langle f_i \circ \text{pr}_i\rangle \colon \prod A_i\to \prod B_i$ for morphisms $f_i\colon A_i\to B_i$ (as on the nLab page I linked to).

Comment: If you need to reserve "product map" for that construction, you'd be justified in using a more creative/obscure name for the map $A\to \prod B_i$.  On balance the morphism $\langle f_i \circ \operatorname{pr}_i\rangle:\prod A_i \to \prod B_i$ has so much more "going on" that it certainly needs/deserves an explicit definition.

Comment: I would call it "tupling". Maybe "infinite/arbitrary/set-indexed tupling" for emphasis. It seems to me that if there was a less obscure/more readily understood term, you'd already be aware of it.